# Is there a way to register a python script at other moments than loading?

Tags: python, scripting

I know that you can register a python script to be exectued when a blend file is opened (if Autorun is checked in the Preferences). It works very well.

I would like to know if I can register a script to be run at other moments than loading. For instance:

- run a script periodically
- run a script before/after saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an '[Application Handler](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.app.handlers.html)' to register code to run after certain events in blender, like rendering, saving, loading files and several other situations.

For example, in the code below, appending the function to the `save_pre` handler would print out "Saving File" just *before* the file is saved:

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    print("Saving File")

bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(my_handler)
```

If you wanted code to execute *after* the file is saved then you would append to `save_post`.

I am not too sure how you would execute code *periodically*, though there is a `scene_update_pre` and `scene_update_post` which runs whenever the scene needs to be updated that you could look into.

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried it and it works exactly as I want!